# Reading C++ float value from buffer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, struct, floating-point

currently i'm working on some client(html5)<->node.js<->server (c++) project. 
Server sends me a structured data (standard C++ structs). I have no problem with reading chars, arrays and int32's inside node.js but I cannot read float value properly.

When I try to treat it as integer - as result i get large number.

For example:
Target value is around 280
Readed value from buffer is: 1133248512

How to map C++ float value to javascript float value using C++ struct buffer?

Comment: Did you try parseFloat function? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: @Boyo this won't parse binary format

Comment: For float numbers, have you tried using a Float32Array object in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the raw bit format of a 32bit Float. This should work to convert it to a native javascript double:

```
function f32bit_double(x) {
    // handle sign bit
    if (x < 0) {
        x += 2147483648;
        s = -1;
    } else {
        s = 1;
    }

    r = x % 8388608; // raw significand
    e = (x-r) >> 23; // raw exponent

    if (e === 0) {
        // subnormal
        e -= 126;
        r = r/8388608;
    } else if (e == 255) {
        // inf or nan
        return r === 0 ? s*Infinity : NaN;
    } else {
        // normalised
        e -= 127;
        r = 1+r/8388608;
    }
    return s*r*Math.pow(2,e);
}
```